# Why does requests response object __bool__ check for 200 <= status < 400?

Tags: python, python-requests

According to the [source of the Requests module](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py), the `__bool__` function is used solely to check if the status code of a response is between 200 and 400.

```
Returns True if :attr:`status_code` is less than 400.
This attribute checks if the status code of the response is between
400 and 600 to see if there was a client error or a server error. If
the status code, is between 200 and 400, this will return True. This
is **not** a check to see if the response code is ``200 OK``.
```

This use of the `__bool__` function made the below code work not as intended:

```
def request_url(url):
    error_message = None
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
    except:
        # Do some other error handling...
        error_message = "Bad request."
        r = None
    return r, error_message

r, error_message = request_url(url)
if r:
    # Do some stuff to the response
    operate_on_response(r)
else:
    # Skip this response object and move to the next.
```

The statement `if r:` returns False when the status code of the url I request is a 500. Even though the exception is NOT triggered, `if r:` returns `False` every time there's a server error. My intention is to test if the response object exists, though.

I'm not asking for a workaround: I know I can just check if the error_message is not `None`. The code above is just an example, not the actual code I'm using.

But, to me, it doesn't seem natural or logical to use the `__bool__` function to check if a status code is between two values. Like I said, I can find a workaround myself, but I'm mainly asking why? Why use the `__bool__` method this way? Is there some logic I'm not seeing?

Comment: It's an excellent use of the `__bool__` method; it'll return false if there was an actual *error*. Status codes in the 2xx and 3xx ranges are *success* status codes.

Comment: If you want to know if `r` is not `None`, just use `if r is not None`.

Comment: Would be better design to have it throw on error statuses, IMO. But there’s the “O” part.

Comment: @Ryan: There is a dedicated method for that.

Comment: BTW, please try to avoid referring to "this" code or "this" behavior in a question title where at all possible -- having a description of what it is the question is about *in the title itself* is less click-baity and lets someone make an informed decision about whether to click through and read the text.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Should be the default. And why not be explicit for this behaviour by making it `if response.successful` instead of `if response`?

Comment: @Ryan, ...can't say I agree; what a given status code means is very contextually-specific. If I'm checking for whether a resource already exists under a name with intent to create a new one, I *want* a 404; needing to have an exception in the common path is unfortunate.

Comment: @Ryan: absolutely not, there are different usecases where an exception would be the wrong thing to have. It depends heavily on the context.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: That’s what the separate function to request without exceptions would be for =)

Comment: @Ryan: it is trivial to add a `response.raise_for_status()` line. Why would using a different, separate function be better? There already are different methods for the different request methods (`.get()`, `.post()`, `.put()`, etc.), I fail to see how complicating those with shadow methods would be better here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Separate parameter, then. `raise_for_status()` is easy to forget, and `__bool__` is easy to be surprised by. (Also, given that `.ok` exists, `__bool__` is a *bad choice*.)

Comment: @Ryan: why? The separate parameter is no easier to remember or forget. And *none of these methods ever return `None`*, so the boolean value of such an object is free to be re-defined.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the tip, I'll avoid that next time!

Comment: @SvenMarnach This is a great workaround, thank you!

Comment: @MartijnPieters "It's an excellent use of the `__bool__` method; it'll return false if there was an actual error."  Good point, I guess I need to change my paradigm of seeing a 500 as an error. To me, getting a response (even a 500) is success when I'm just trying to test if a response was received. Thanks for the perspective!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The method returns `True` if the request was *successful*. The status codes in the 2xx and 3xx ranges all indicate a *correct and successful* response, while other status codes all indicate errors.

Under the hood, the `__bool__` method is essentially an alias for the [`response.ok` attribute](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.ok):

> Returns `True` if `status_code` is less than 400, `False` if not.
>
> This attribute checks if the status code of the response is between 400 and 600 to see if there was a client error or a server error. If the status code is between 200 and 400, this will return `True`. This is **not** a check to see if the response code is 200 OK.

This echoes the [`response.raise_for_status()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status), which will raise an `HTTPError` exception when there is an 'error' status code.

Any function or method in the `requests` API that can return a `Response` instance, will *always* do so, or raise an exception. You can't ever get a `None` or other false-y value from the API, so there is no other usecase for testing for a boolean value. As such, the boolean value of a response can be overloaded to mean *anything*, and here it is used to make it easy to test for the 'okayness' of the response:

```
response = requests.get(...)
if response:
    # success! yay, do something meaningful with the response data
```

This fits some use-cases better than raising an exception for the opposite state, where you got an error status from the server.

Comment: Also helpful is [RFC Change behaviour of Response.ok in 3.0 #2645](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2645). (The source documentation for `Response.__bool__()` is the same as `Response.ok()`.)

Comment: Specifically to OP’s question kennethreitz’s comment is relevant:
“when designed, 'ok' meant 'not an error'. 300 is not an error. I still think should be the case.  e.g. '.ok' isnt OMG ALL IS PERFECT, it is NOTHING APPEARS IMMEDIATELY BROKEN”

Comment: +1 and accepted. Thank you for explaining the alternative perspective! In my mind, I was treating even a 500 error as a "Yay we got a response back from the server and the connection wasn't reset, that's a successful start!" I'm in Website Quality Assurance if that explains anything.

Comment: @jarcobi889: and that's exactly why the API doesn't raise an exception unless you explicitly ask for it with `raise_for_status()` either. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Wonderful explanation and exactly why I come here for answers. Thank you!